# align doesn't indent multiple lines of C code correctly

Tags: comment, align

This is my simple C code block:

```
int main() { // the enty function
        in x = 100; // my new variable
        for(int i=1; i<2012; ++i) { // loop a lot
                x -= i;
        }
} /* end of all things */
```

I want to indent this block into:

```
int main() {                        // the enty function
        int x = 100;                // my new variable
        for(int i=1; i<2012; ++i) { // loop a lot
                x -= i;
        }
}                                   /* end of all things */
```

But after I select this region and `M-x align`, it becomes:

```
int main() {                    // the enty function
        in      x  = 100;       // my new variable
        for(int i=1; i<2012; ++i) {     // loop a lot
                x -= i;
        }
}                               /* end of all things */
```

If `align` cannot handle all comments to the same column, that's fine, but I don't understand why this line of the code:

```
            in x = 100; // my new variable
```

becomes:

```
            in      x  = 100;       // my new variable
```

See, it adds multiple spaces around `x`. Why?

FYI: I did this in Emacs both with my `.emacs.d` and without my `.emacs.d`(emacs -q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` is aligning those `//` comments to the value of `comment-column` in that buffer, which will be column 32 by default.  Your `for` statement extends beyond that column, so it is out of alignment.

See `C-h f comment-set-column`.  Use that, and then `M-x align` again.

> See, it adds multiple spaces around x. Why?

Because it has aligned the `=` characters in the two assignments.

Note that alignment is flexible and complex (and sometimes may seem overzealous, as with your assignment statements).  Different modes can have different rules, using different values, so the same rules won't apply in all buffers.  See `C-h v align-rules-list` for more (I believe the rules you're asking about here are `c++-comment` and `c-assignment` respectively).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed `comment-column` problem years ago, I though it would be dynamically, like 4->8->12->16, or something like this. I'll check `comment-set-column` and `align-rules-list` for more info.